# Vb script with excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets in Excel - `all` and `ArticlesA`.

I want to loop through the values in column `B` of the `all` sheet and see if the value is also in column `B` of the `ArticlesA` sheet.
If the value exists I want to copy the value from `ArticlesA` into a new column in `all`.

```
Sub stock()

    Dim iall, i2, i3, k, kk, z

    Dim wsall As Worksheet
    Set wsall = Sheets("all")

    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = Sheets("ArticlesA")
    iall = wsall.Range("B1").End(4).Row
    i2 = ws2.Range("B1").End(4).Row

    With wsall
        For k = 2 To iall
            z = .Range("B" & k)
            For kk = 1 To i2
                If z = ws2.Range("B" & kk) Then

                    Range("J" & kk).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 10

                End If
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your question was a bit hard to follow (thus the close votes).  I've reworded it and hopefully the meaning is still correct?  As @EganWolf said in his answer - your code isn't doing what you ask.  It's colouring the row in column `J` of the `Activesheet` rather than copying values to the `all` sheet.  Feel free to roll back the update if I've got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not doing what you said, but if you want to fix it, just specify the worksheet in line where you set a color of row:

```
ws2.Range("J" & kk).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
```